# Fading effect when readings jump between high and low to reduce variablility

Tags: c++, audio, arduino, smoothing

I have created a circuit using an arduino that powers LED strips that listen to microphone inputs, and output the number of LEDs to light up depending on the noise level in the room. This works great for music etc.

My issue is that the output from the microphone is highly variable, and the LEDs are quite "flashy" in the sense that they respond too much to changes in decibel readings.

The levels I'm using are fine, and I'm happy with my gain settings.

[image]

The image above shows an example of a level meter (specifically for Logic Pro X). This level meter does the same as mine, however it has a "holding" period where the peak stays where it is and gradually drops off if the level reported by the audio is low.

This effect is important because it suits reduces the flashing between high and low volumes.
Mine currently does not have this effect, which is why the LED's are so variable.

Does anyone know of any smoothing/fading methods I could investigate the use case of so my level meter doesn't appear so jumpy?

Comment: The usual way of doing this is to filter the signal using a low pass filter. Look for IIR low pass filter on the net.  That's also usually accompanied by a reduction of the sampling rate (a process called decimation), although rthis  would only help you if you need to reduce the actual refresh rate of the LEDs.

Comment: You may also want to look at how compressors work, as the gain stage uses the technique you are looking for to display peaks.

Comment: I see, I'm familiar with compressors and I'll try and find a method of implementing the gain stage functionality you mentioned. 

I've also removed the request for libraries, I hope this removes the need for the close vote. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smoothing to make the readings less sporadic and gradually dropping the peak are two different effects commonly used in sound level meters like those on a graphic equalizer.

Smoothing can be pretty simple if you're reading a sensor at regular intervals.  (You should probably check the datasheet to determine whether your sensor is already doing some filtering.)  Instead of displaying the actual reading, you incorporate each reading into a weighted average, effectively making a low-pass filter.

```
current_reading = read_the_sensor();
value_to_display = k1 * value_to_display + k2 * current_reading;
```

You choose two constants `k1` and `k2` such that `k1 + k2 == 1` and `k1 > k2`.  If you're working with integer arithmetic, you can approximate this by using integers for `k1` and `k2` and dividing the the result by their sum:

```
value_to_display = (k1 * value_to_display + k2 * current_reading) / (k1 + k2);
```

I usually start with values like `k1 = 4` and `k2 = 1` and adjust them until the displayed value feels right.

The falling peak effect can be accomplished in similar way.

```
if (value_to_display > peak) {
  peak = value_to_display;
} else {
  peak = k3 * peak / k4;
}
```

In this case, you want `k3` to be slightly less than `k4`, such as `k3 = 9` and `k4 = 10`.  The exact values will depend on how frequently you're updating the values and how fast you want it to fall.

If the value is climbing, the peak rides it up.  When the value drops, the peak will drop slowly.

Comment: Also, if anyone else finds this thread, to increase the speed of peak fall you should make the values of `k3` and `k4` lower and vice versa for decreasing speed of peak fall. For mine I chose 15 and 16 and it works well.